# i have an issue in javascript,am building an ecommerce application and i have written the codes for the images to show but it is not still showing

Tags: javascript, java, css, jsp, java-ee-7

I have an issue in JavaScript, am building an ecommerce application and I have written the codes for the images to show but it is not still showing here are the codes for the images to show

This is the codes I have written for displaying the images for the category section

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>
<%-- 
    Document   : index.jsp
    Created on : 13-Mar-2017, 21:31:29
    Author     : jones
--%>
<sql:query var="categories" dataSource="jdbc/TKElectronicsStore">
    SELECT * FROM category  *MySQL code*
</sql:query>
            <div id="indexLeftColumn">
                <div id="welcomeText">
                     <p> [ welcome text ] </p>
                     We are your one-stop shop for everything electronic. Shop our wide range of products from 
            Stabilizers, Cameras, Washing Machines, Home Theatres, Phones, Speakers, Accessories, Televisions, 
            Cameras and Home Cinemas...we have got it all and we have got you covered. And what's better, we deliver right
            to your doorstep at spanking prices!!
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="indexRightColumn">
                <c:forEach var="category" items="${categories.rows}">
                    <div class="categoryBox">
                        <a href="category?${category.id}">
                         <span class="categoryLabelText">${category.name}</span> (different categories Cameras, Stabilizers e.t.c)
 <img src="${initParam.categoryImagePath}${category.name}.jpg" alt="${category.name}"> (displaying the images for the categories)
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </c:forEach>
            </div>
```

This is the codes I have written for displaying the images for the products section, I have tried looking for the solution that's why I came here pls help me I need to finish this on time
Thanks in Advance

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>
<%-- 
    Document   : category.jsp
    Created on : 14-Mar-2017, 22:23:57
    Author     : jones
--%>
<sql:query var="categories" dataSource="jdbc/TKElectronicsStore">
    SELECT * FROM category
</sql:query>

    <sql:query var="selectedCategory" dataSource="jdbc/TKElectronicsStore">
        SELECT name FROM category WHERE id = ? (sql code to select the category id)
        <sql:param value="${pageContext.request.queryString}" />
    </sql:query>

        <sql:query var="categoryProducts" dataSource="jdbc/TKElectronicsStore">
            SELECT * FROM product where category_id = ?
            <sql:param value="${pageContext.request.queryString}" />
        </sql:query>

            <div id="categoryLeftColumn">
                <c:forEach var="category" items="${categories.rows}">
                    <c:choose>
               <c:when test="${category.id == pageContext.request.queryString}">
                            <div class="categoryButton" id="selectedCategory">
                           <span class="categoryText">${category.name}</span>
                            </div>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>
                    <a href="category?${category.id}" class="categoryButton">
                                <div class="categoryText">${category.name}</div>
                            </a>
                        </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>

                </c:forEach>

            </div>

            <div id="categoryRightColumn">
                <p id="categoryTitle">${selectedCategory.rows[0].name}</p>

                <table id="productTable">
     <c:forEach var="product" items="${categoryProducts.rows}" varStatus="iter">
                <tr class="${((iter.index % 2) == 0) ? 'lightBlue' : 'white'}">
                        <td>
<img src="${initParam.productImagePath}${product.name}.jpg" alt="${product.name}"> (displaying images for the product table)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ${product.name}
                            <br>
                            <span class="smallText">${product.description}</span>
                        </td>
                        <td> &pound; ${product.price} </td>
                        <td>
                          <form action="addToCart" method="post">
                 <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="${product.id}">
                                <input type="submit" value="add to cart">
                            </form>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Comment: Javascript?  Please isolate this issue to your java and/or your other code if any exists.  Show rendered markup perhaps?

Comment: ". . .doorstep at spanking prices!!" please don't spank me.

Comment: tnx @ mark, I wish I can spank u